Как для каждой категории создать свою страницу?


И мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эти категории открывалась для каждой категории своя страница, со своими определенными товарами? Основная проблема заключалась в том, что я создал 1 страницу для всех категорий, но для каждой отдельной я присваивал id через '?', и когда я пытался к любой из этих категорий добавить подгрузку картинок, добавление hrefa либо сносилось, либо страница перезагружалась и эффекта по сути 0. Буду признателен за ответ.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Тут много вариантов может быть. Все зависит от архитектуры проекта в целом. SPA или SSR? А можно и без роутинга вообще это реализовать. Так что сначала определитесь что вы хотите

архитектура  ssr

@user27818635 ну самый простой способ это создать для каждой категории статическую страничку и залить на сервер, на главной просто сослаться на эти странички. Но так конечно не делается (ну или делается на маленьких статических сайтах). Нормальный SSR должен генерировать страницу по запросу. Вам нужно копать в сторону серверной разработки. В SSR я мало что понимаю, работал только с CSR SPA

Если у Вас одна страница, то поиграйте с видимостью CSS. Нажал на категорию → Отобразил её., а остальные скрыл. Привязать триггер, что при отображении подгружать содержимое категории
